# RunTimeINIT: *** terminating: Java arch not 64 Bit or not detected

Tags: java, sikuli, sikuli-x

I am getting this error while running Sikulix from CMD with command

```
java -jar sikulix.jar
```

complete error is:

```
[error] RunTimeINIT:  *** terminating: 
Java arch not 64 Bit or not detected (java 8-32 version 1.8 vm 25.181-b13 class 52.0 arch null)
```

I am not able to find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like a java 64 bit is required (because of native code dependencies) and you only have a java 32 bit installed.

Comment: Thanks! .... It worked :) ... Wonder why i wasn't able to understand this